# Как реализовать аналог $(document).ready на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Тоже самое только на JS. Как перевести?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_error_message_frontend + div > div:last-child label").addClass("last");
    })
```

Comment: Вам сюда: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ // Аналог $(document).ready(function(){
  // Если должен быть найден один элемент
  if((e = document.querySelector("#form_error_message_frontend + div > div:last-child label")) !== null)
    e.classList.add('last'); // Аналог выборки и присвоения класса
  // Если элементов будет много
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#form_error_message_frontend + div > div:last-child label"), function(e){
   e.classList.add('last');
  });
});
```

Comment: Требуется не `querySelector`, а `querySelectorAll` плюс итерация по возвращаемому `NodeList`.

Comment: @VisioN, класс `last` недвусмысленно намекает что найдётся только один элемент, а значит можно искать через `querySelector`. Хотя если у ТС'а не так, то перепишем :)

Comment: Не совсем так :) Хоть это и может противоречить здравому смыслу, но элементов `label` в последнем блоке может быть несколько. В этом случае, чисто логически, добавляемый класс `"last"` может относиться не к последнему `label`, а ко всем `label` в последнем блоке.

Comment: Я знаю, друг мой, но я понадеялся на здравый смысл автора :) 
Если ответ примется, то смысл на месте, ежели нет - перепишем на цикл, делов-то...

Comment: Хорошо, будем надеяться :) Но тогда, чтобы не вышло неувязочки, для `querySelector` можно добавить проверку на наличие возвращаемого элемента перед обращением к свойству `classList`: а ну как `undefined` вернет?

Comment: @VisioN, Надежда, мой... [что-то там, забыл] земной!
Можно и проверочки добавить, и функции помощники написать, и уменьшить страшный тэг поиска... Много чего можно.
И по настоятельной просьбе написал для многих элементов привязку.

Comment: Компас :) Однако за качество даваемых ответов нужно бороться, а то что ж тяп-ляп делать.. Так автор и не научится ничему. А исправления годные, спасибо, плюсую.

Comment: @VisioN, добавил эту проверку. И да - `querySelector` возвращает `null`, а не `undefined`.

Comment: Да, действительно... один черт не истину.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22633/discussion-between-thedoctor-and-vision).

Answer (score 21):

хороший ответ есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

[90+%](http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded) браузеров покроет вот такое решение для ожидания окончания загрузки

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

для [95+%](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) браузеров можно использовать методы querySelector/querySelectorAll

```
var el = document.querySelector("#form_error_message_frontend + div > div:last-child label");
el.className += el.className ? ' last' : 'last'
```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вам будет достаточно добавить отложенную загрузку скрипта атрибутом "defer" в `<script>`
Так скрипт дождется загрузки всего DOM дерева, после чего запустится.

Comment: Можно пруф? Первый раз об этом слышу...

Comment: "A script that will not run until after the page has loaded"
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp

Comment: Осталось понять, что значит "page has loaded". Потому что не нужно ждать подгрузки картинок, чтобы начать выполнять скрипт.

Comment: Думаю, это случается после DOMContentLoaded, то  есть загрузка картинок и прочего не учитывается, только ДОМ дерево.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Пример</title>
<script language="JavaScript">
function startFunction() {
alert("Hi there!");
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```