# Удалить элемент через QuerySelector

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Есть таблица  с данными, если через  Chrome - "просмотреть код" выбрать таблицу и сделать "hide lement" , то все работает, НО до  1-й  перезагрузки. Как в JS  код  добавить автоматические  удаление/скрытие таблицы - если selector такого вида:  "body > p:nth-child(5) > span > table" ? Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) скрыть `document.querySelector('body > p:nth-child(5) > span > table').style.display = 'none'`

2) удалить`document.querySelector('body > p:nth-child(5) > span > table').remove()`

Если вам это при загрузке страницы надо делать то поставьте это на какое-нибудь событие. А по хорошему не отдавайте ее с бекенда вообще.

Comment: А как можно удалить  элементы из потока??? Просто  HTML генериться, отображается таблица - далее  пока  не  нажмешь  "Посмотреть  код" - таблицу  невозможно удалить (((  - а  далее все работает.

Comment: @Максим ну так в девтулсе вы удаляете не на сайте для всех пользователей, а у себя только конкретно на своей машине, конкретно в текущем браузере и только на данной загрузке страницы. Или я вас вообще не понимаю. Это вам нужно на сервере искать файл какой то расширения .js и добавлять то что я написал или файл .php (который генерит страницу может и не php) и там затирать

Comment: Только у  себя  в консоли. Просто данный код  хотел  закинуть  в js на  body onload=func()  - но так  не  работает. И если  выполнять через  консоль,  то только  когда  исходник  глянешь - видимо особенность генерации  страницы (((

Comment: хз, можете вот в эту https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-document-ready-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-js сторону глянуть или window.load. Если ничего не работает то есть вероятность что таблица у вас генерится(может ajax) уже после всего где-то в js, там и ищите