# Исполнения кода раньше загрузки библиотеки. (в JQuery .html())

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу отобразить сгенерированный html на странице.
Html - это график генерируемый python библиотекой bokeh.

Пример html генерируемого bokeh:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bokeh Plot</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.2.0.min.css" type="text/css"/>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
    </script>


</head>


<body>


<div class="bk-root" id="540005a2-3a90-40ce-8aba-e78a74e23a7f" data-root-id="1001"></div>


<script type="application/json" id="1120">
    {
        "8c457342-a68e-4f70-b27a-a5531bc67fd5": {
            "roots": {
                "references": [
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "items": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1047",
                                    "type": "LegendItem"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": "1046",
                        "type": "Legend"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "callback": null,
                            "data": {
                                "x": [
                                    1,
                                    2,
                                    3,
                                    4,
                                    5
                                ],
                                "y": [
                                    6,
                                    7,
                                    2,
                                    4,
                                    5
                                ]
                            },
                            "selected": {
                                "id": "1054",
                                "type": "Selection"
                            },
                            "selection_policy": {
                                "id": "1055",
                                "type": "UnionRenderers"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1035",
                        "type": "ColumnDataSource"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1025",
                        "type": "SaveTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "axis_label": "y",
                            "formatter": {
                                "id": "1041",
                                "type": "BasicTickFormatter"
                            },
                            "ticker": {
                                "id": "1018",
                                "type": "BasicTicker"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1017",
                        "type": "LinearAxis"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "label": {
                                "value": "Temp."
                            },
                            "renderers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1038",
                                    "type": "GlyphRenderer"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": "1047",
                        "type": "LegendItem"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "line_alpha": 0.1,
                            "line_color": "#1f77b4",
                            "line_width": 2,
                            "x": {
                                "field": "x"
                            },
                            "y": {
                                "field": "y"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1037",
                        "type": "Line"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1026",
                        "type": "ResetTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1018",
                        "type": "BasicTicker"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "overlay": {
                                "id": "1045",
                                "type": "BoxAnnotation"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1024",
                        "type": "BoxZoomTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1027",
                        "type": "HelpTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "dimension": 1,
                            "ticker": {
                                "id": "1018",
                                "type": "BasicTicker"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1021",
                        "type": "Grid"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "callback": null
                        },
                        "id": "1006",
                        "type": "DataRange1d"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "active_drag": "auto",
                            "active_inspect": "auto",
                            "active_multi": null,
                            "active_scroll": "auto",
                            "active_tap": "auto",
                            "tools": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1022",
                                    "type": "PanTool"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1023",
                                    "type": "WheelZoomTool"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1024",
                                    "type": "BoxZoomTool"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1025",
                                    "type": "SaveTool"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1026",
                                    "type": "ResetTool"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1027",
                                    "type": "HelpTool"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "id": "1028",
                        "type": "Toolbar"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1008",
                        "type": "LinearScale"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "text": "simple line example"
                        },
                        "id": "1002",
                        "type": "Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "source": {
                                "id": "1035",
                                "type": "ColumnDataSource"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1039",
                        "type": "CDSView"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "data_source": {
                                "id": "1035",
                                "type": "ColumnDataSource"
                            },
                            "glyph": {
                                "id": "1036",
                                "type": "Line"
                            },
                            "hover_glyph": null,
                            "muted_glyph": null,
                            "nonselection_glyph": {
                                "id": "1037",
                                "type": "Line"
                            },
                            "selection_glyph": null,
                            "view": {
                                "id": "1039",
                                "type": "CDSView"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1038",
                        "type": "GlyphRenderer"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1010",
                        "type": "LinearScale"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1041",
                        "type": "BasicTickFormatter"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1022",
                        "type": "PanTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "line_color": "#1f77b4",
                            "line_width": 2,
                            "x": {
                                "field": "x"
                            },
                            "y": {
                                "field": "y"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1036",
                        "type": "Line"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "callback": null
                        },
                        "id": "1004",
                        "type": "DataRange1d"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1054",
                        "type": "Selection"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "axis_label": "x",
                            "formatter": {
                                "id": "1043",
                                "type": "BasicTickFormatter"
                            },
                            "ticker": {
                                "id": "1013",
                                "type": "BasicTicker"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1012",
                        "type": "LinearAxis"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1043",
                        "type": "BasicTickFormatter"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1023",
                        "type": "WheelZoomTool"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "below": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1012",
                                    "type": "LinearAxis"
                                }
                            ],
                            "center": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1016",
                                    "type": "Grid"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1021",
                                    "type": "Grid"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": "1046",
                                    "type": "Legend"
                                }
                            ],
                            "left": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1017",
                                    "type": "LinearAxis"
                                }
                            ],
                            "renderers": [
                                {
                                    "id": "1038",
                                    "type": "GlyphRenderer"
                                }
                            ],
                            "title": {
                                "id": "1002",
                                "type": "Title"
                            },
                            "toolbar": {
                                "id": "1028",
                                "type": "Toolbar"
                            },
                            "x_range": {
                                "id": "1004",
                                "type": "DataRange1d"
                            },
                            "x_scale": {
                                "id": "1008",
                                "type": "LinearScale"
                            },
                            "y_range": {
                                "id": "1006",
                                "type": "DataRange1d"
                            },
                            "y_scale": {
                                "id": "1010",
                                "type": "LinearScale"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1001",
                        "subtype": "Figure",
                        "type": "Plot"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1055",
                        "type": "UnionRenderers"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {},
                        "id": "1013",
                        "type": "BasicTicker"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "bottom_units": "screen",
                            "fill_alpha": {
                                "value": 0.5
                            },
                            "fill_color": {
                                "value": "lightgrey"
                            },
                            "left_units": "screen",
                            "level": "overlay",
                            "line_alpha": {
                                "value": 1.0
                            },
                            "line_color": {
                                "value": "black"
                            },
                            "line_dash": [
                                4,
                                4
                            ],
                            "line_width": {
                                "value": 2
                            },
                            "render_mode": "css",
                            "right_units": "screen",
                            "top_units": "screen"
                        },
                        "id": "1045",
                        "type": "BoxAnnotation"
                    },
                    {
                        "attributes": {
                            "ticker": {
                                "id": "1013",
                                "type": "BasicTicker"
                            }
                        },
                        "id": "1016",
                        "type": "Grid"
                    }
                ],
                "root_ids": [
                    "1001"
                ]
            },
            "title": "Bokeh Application",
            "version": "1.2.0"
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var fn = function () {
            Bokeh.safely(function () {
                (function (root) {
                    function embed_document(root) {

                        var docs_json = document.getElementById('1120').textContent;
                        var render_items = [{
                            "docid": "8c457342-a68e-4f70-b27a-a5531bc67fd5",
                            "roots": {"1001": "540005a2-3a90-40ce-8aba-e78a74e23a7f"}
                        }];
                        root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                    }

                    if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                    } else {
                        var attempts = 0;
                        var timer = setInterval(function (root) {
                            if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                                embed_document(root);
                                clearInterval(timer);
                            }
                            attempts++;
                            if (attempts > 100) {
                                console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                                clearInterval(timer);
                            }
                        }, 10, root)
                    }
                })(window);
            });
        };
        if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
        else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    })();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

В Html есть скипта загрузки bokeh библиотеки

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

А также скрипт инициализации

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var fn = function () {
            Bokeh.safely(function () {
                (function (root) {
                    function embed_document(root) {

                        var docs_json = document.getElementById('1120').textContent;
                        var render_items = [{
                            "docid": "8c457342-a68e-4f70-b27a-a5531bc67fd5",
                            "roots": {"1001": "540005a2-3a90-40ce-8aba-e78a74e23a7f"}
                        }];
                        root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                    }

                    if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                    } else {
                        var attempts = 0;
                        var timer = setInterval(function (root) {
                            if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                                embed_document(root);
                                clearInterval(timer);
                            }
                            attempts++;
                            if (attempts > 100) {
                                console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
                                clearInterval(timer);
                            }
                        }, 10, root)
                    }
                })(window);
            });
        };
        if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
        else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    })();
</script>
```

Проблема в том что скрипт инициализации запускается раньше чем успевает загрузиться Bokeh библиотека.
Вследствие чего содержимое не отображается на странице.
И вылетает следующая ошибка:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Bokeh is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at DOMEval (jquery.js:124)
    at domManip (jquery.js:5945)
    at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery.js:6081)
    at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js:6175)
    at access (jquery.js:3962)
    at jQuery.fn.init.html (jquery.js:6142)
    at eval (result.controller.js?63d7:487)
    at handleData (result.controller.js?63d7:447)
    at renderHtml (result.controller.js?63d7:485)
```

Если вставить график ещё раз то он отрисовыается нормально.
Вопрос можно как-то это исправить без изменения генерируемого html?

Пример вставки html (на всякий случай)

```
const elem = angular.element(`#${targetElemId}`);
elem.html(generated);
```

Comment: засуньте все в событие `onload`

Comment: В тег script добавить defer? https://learn.javascript.ru/external-script , почитайте о последовательности

Comment: onload не помогло. Отрисовка вообще не вызвалась.

Comment: defer тоже попробовал. Тоже не помогло. И я бы все же не хотел модифицировать вставляемый html.
Но проверяя ваш совет поробовал ещё одну вещь:
Вместо скрипта загрузки библиотеки вставил исходники этой самой библиотеки и... Всё заработало
Я не понимаю что проиходит)
И это естественно не приемлимое решение проблемы

Comment: Ну ситуация впринципе понятна у вас библиотека еще качается, а исполняемый скрипт уже тут как тут. попробуйдет может это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/414516/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3-document-ready-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-js

Comment: Обошёл проблему включив в библиотеке bokeh режим создания offline html.
Т.е. код библиотеки вставляется на прямую.
В этом случае всё происходит в нужном порядке.